# Im writing a cipher, but it will only work if i ignore spaces. Is there a way to make it ignore spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

Im using the della porta cipher and it works almost perfectly, the only issue i have is when there are spaces in my message. When there are no spaces in my message, the code converts it through the cipher just fine. Is there a way i can make the code ignore spaces in the message and move on to the next character?

```
package DellaPorta2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DellaPorta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
        String message = input.nextLine();
        char[] messageArray = message.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray(); 
        System.out.print("Enter your keyword: ");
        String key = input.nextLine();
        char[] keyArray = key.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
        String convertedMessage = String.valueOf(encryptMessage(messageArray, keyArray));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(getKeyString(keyArray).toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(message.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(convertedMessage.toUpperCase());

    }

    public static char[] encryptMessage(char[] messageArray, char[] keyArray) {

         final char  DellaPortaArray[][] =    { {'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm' },
                                                {'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' },
                                                {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k' },
                                                {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' },
                                                {'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' },
                                                {'s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' },
                                                {'t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' },
                                                {'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' },
                                                {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
                                                {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' },
                                                {'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c' },
                                                {'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b' },
                                                {'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a' }};

        char[] convertedMessage = new char[messageArray.length];

        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < messageArray.length; x++) {
            char characterOfMessage = messageArray[x];
            char characterOfKey = keyArray[(y % keyArray.length)];

            if (characterOfMessage == ' ') {
                convertedMessage[x] = ' ';

            }


            else convertedMessage[x] = DellaPortaArray[(((int)characterOfKey)-97) / 2][((int)characterOfMessage)-97]; y++;


        }   return convertedMessage;
    }



    public static String getKeyString(char[] keyArray){
        String newKeyword = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) { newKeyword = newKeyword + (keyArray[i]); }
        return newKeyword;
    }

    public static String getMessageString(char[] messageArray){
        String newMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) { newMessage = newMessage + (messageArray[i]); }
        return newMessage;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to your incorrect code indentation, your code isn't doing what you think.

`else`, without braces, will execute only the very next statement. That's it. So, that `y++` that's hanging off of the end there, completely invisible? That'll be run whether `characterOfMessage` is a space or not.

Presumably you want it to run only when there's a non-space there, so that a space means literal nothing whatsoever. Use braces for the else too. (General style guide tip: If you brace up one branch in an if, brace them all. In fact, many style guides suggest that if an if statement involves an `else`, always brace.)

Comment: This type of error can be avoided if you use an IDE. Let it format the code after any change.